# what is the best way to combine some Alamofire to queue?

Tags: swift, alamofire, nsoperationqueue

I'm new to Swift and know almost nothing about threads, operations, queues, etc. And I have for example initial page in my app, where I use 3 alamofire requests like so:

```
request1 => request2

request3

                     => segue to the next view
```

It means, that requests `1` and `2` are serial, but `3` can be parallel, and segue only when ALL requests are done and handled.

I've tried `OperationsQueue` and at least it was faster =) but at Xcode's console I see that some code inside both Alamofire's success case's are done after segue was perform.

So what is the best practice to combine up to 5 Alamofire **without make them nested**? 
Or how correct handle async functions with `OperationQueue`?

Comment: Learn `DispatchGroup` and make some effort. Once you face an issue, post the actual code in your question and get the best possible help from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DispatchGroup can sometimes cause problems like **deadlock**. You can use completion block. Completion block funcs are async functions.

```
func 1(completion:@escaping () -> ()) {

   func 2(completion:@escaping () -> ()) {

      func 3(completion:@escaping () -> ()) {

       //You dont never know when func1 is finished. So you have to write nested functions. 
       //In this situation func2 waits func1. And func3 wait for func1 and func2. 
       //You can write the func3 at the top. This is you choice. 
      }

   }

}
```

Comment: so I'm trying not to use nested functions, because nested Alamofire works fine, but when there are 4-5 chained requests it seems weird . my point is how wrap async functions in serial completion, like `.then` in JavaScript)

Comment: Then you can look DispatchGroup  enter() - leave()

Comment: thanks a lot for idea, `enter() - leave()` works perfect for my problem! `.notify`  call segue after all requests handled